# What causes a 'numpy.float64' object not callable TypeError when attempting to retrieve the newest CSV file in a folder using Python?

Tags: python, file, directory, glob

I tried to get the latest csv file in a folder in Python. I had the same code that already worked with a folder with images files. However recently I got a

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

My code is:

```
latest_file = max(glob.glob("forecasting_csv/*"), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Tried to find some other way but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Have you used `max` as a variable name elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Can you show full error?

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[160], line 2
      1 list_of_files = glob.glob("forecasting_csv/*")
----> 2 latest_file = max(list_of_files,  key=os.path.getmtime)
      3 latest_file

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable`

Comment: So that error means that either `max` or `os.path.getmtime` is a float64 rather than a function (or other callable). If you do `print(max)` and `print(os.path.getmtime)` just before the line that gives the error, that should demonstrate which is the problem.

Comment: @slothrop Thanks! I just checked it again and found out I actually used it somewhere else. Sorry my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

I just found another way:

```
path  ="forecasting_csv/"
most_recent_file = None
most_recent_time = 0
for entry in os.scandir(path):
    if entry.is_file():
        # get the modification time of the file using entry.stat().st_mtime_ns
        mod_time = entry.stat().st_mtime_ns
        if mod_time > most_recent_time:
            # update the most recent file and its modification time
            most_recent_file = entry.name
            most_recent_time = mod_time
```